# how to detect orb feature in a selected square region in a video using opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, mouseevent

AM doing a project on selected object tracking as part of it i have to detect orb feature in a selected square region a video using opencv and python.but this code doesn't work.please help me and thanks in advance

```
import numpy as np  
import cv2  
rect = (0,0,0,0)  
startPoint = False  
endPoint = False  

def on_mouse(event,x,y,flags,params):  

    global rect,startPoint,endPoint  

    # get mouse click  
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:  

        if startPoint == True and endPoint == True:  
            startPoint = False  
            endPoint = False  
            rect = (0, 0, 0, 0)  

        if startPoint == False:  
            rect = (x, y, 0, 0)  
            startPoint = True  
        elif endPoint == False:  
            rect = (rect[0], rect[1], x, y)  
            endPoint = True  

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('demo.mp4')  
waitTime = 50  

#Reading the first frame  
(grabbed, frame) = cap.read()  
#taking frames one by one  
while(cap.isOpened()):  

    (grabbed, frame) = cap.read()  

    cv2.namedWindow('frame')  
    cv2.setMouseCallback('frame', on_mouse)      
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  
    orb = cv2.ORB_create()  
    kp = orb.detect(gray,None)  
    img2=frame.copy()  
    frame=cv2.drawKeypoints(gray,kp,img2,color=(0,255,0),flags=0)  
    cv2.imshow('frame', img2)  
#waitkey  
    if cv2.waitKey(10)==27:  
        break  
        cv2.imshow('Video', img2)  
cap.release()  
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Where are you using the points selected in the callback? Looks like you are just detecting all the key points and drawing them. What do you mean by doesn't work? You need to be more specific.

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your code and any error messages!

Comment: ** i don't know how to use the points selected in the callback** @xthestreams

Comment: **i could detect the orb feature but am not able to select a square**@matthew cliatt

Comment: @anaghakbabu the call back sets a global variable rect with x,y coordinates that you can use to draw a rectangle or only do the orb on that section of the image.